# Using Memcache in PHP with OOP

Tags: php, oop, memcached

I have a very heavy class definition that's MySQL dependent (i.e. can be slow sometimes).

I've successfully installed and started using Memcache library in PHP. This allows me to store entire objects without having to re-query them.

However, I've extended my class to auto update the database of any changes. I use `__get` and `__set` to track changes, and then update on `__destruct`

What I cannot figure out how to test is whether `__destruct` is called when Memcache deletes the object.

Any one know for a fact / have a suggestion on how to test it?

Comment: I doubt Memcached executes anything when it throws away cached data. Memcached is not a PHP specific thing and it only stores *data*.

Comment: Mmm I don't think the object's destructor is called at all when Memcache deletes an object... because it would be deleted by Memcache and not by PHP

Comment: Memcache has nothing to do with the destructor method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, memcache will not destruct the object. You're object is constantly `__sleep()`'ing and `__wakeup()`'ing. But since PHP is not the one destroying or losing the object the destructor is never called. There's an outside chance your caching library is removing the object from memcache after it's expired and destroying the object thus calling `__destruct()`.. but that would depend on the implementation.

Comment: Memcache invokes serialization?

Comment: @Mikhail Most caching engines are just key => value stores. It can't store an object.. just simple data types like ints and strings. So your object is converted into a string via `serialize()` and `unserialize()`. When this happens PHP invokes the magic methods `__sleep()` and `__wakeup()` in case anything special needs to happen when performing these operations. Look at memcache's status page to view what's currently in memory and you'll see the string-representation of your objects.

Comment: oh gosh I thought it was preserving an actual memory chunk. I can save time on __wakeup() but perhaps not on __sleep